# Sikuli 1.1 observe behaviour

Tags: python, automation, sikuli, observers

I am new to create code. I try using Sikuli with observe function. When I use the script it does the thing one time and then never again.

```
while(1):
def Handler(event):
    stopObserver
    click(image)
    event.repeat(1)       
    pass

    while(1):
        onAppear("image", Handler)
        observe(FOREVER)
```

What is wrong with the script? Why does the script only click the image one time. If the image appears a second time nothing happens.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to achieve and based on that it will be easier to point you the right way.

Comment: I want to understand the observe function. I read the information from [Sikuli Homepage](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html?highlight=observ#observingvisualeventsinaregion). I wrote a test to wait for an image (e.g. calculator appears then click "1" "+" "1" "=").

Comment: Today the script works after a reboot (?). When I do not use `event.repeat(1)` the script don't work. The sikuli pseudo scipt don't use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observer in Sikuli can be a bit confusing at times.

Generally, you register one or more events to be observed with a `Region` using `onXXXXX` (observe-events or just events). Then you start the observation in a `Region` by starting its observer and later stopping it again as needed.

However, if you do not need the observer run in the background while you continue interacting with other areas of your screen, in most cases it would be easier to use timed `wait`. You can do it like this:

```
wait(pattern, waitTime)
```

Here the wait will only last for `waitTime` before the script flow continues.

Comment: How can I start an observer for a Region? I use `observe(FOREVER)` one time at the end of the code. I thought this starts all defined `onAppear(xxx)` defined before. Do I have to use `event.repaet(1)` in the handler?

Comment: Ok, I tried different code snippets. In the meantime my code works without `event.repeat(1)`. I moved the second block that starts with`while(1)` 4 spaces left to start `observe(FOREVER)`.